# Getting out of memory error while using android service

Tags: android

I have an android application that gets some post from server by Volley
I want to play a music whenever a new post is added to server for this case I store the old count in a shared prefrence variable and I get the list size from server every 7 second and compare to old count
If they be difrerent,the music will play

Every thing works well but after some hours I get this out of memory error:

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: thread creation failed
    at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1050)
    at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:152)
    atcom.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:79)
    atcom.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:105)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:115)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my internet service code:

```
public class InternetService7 extends Service {
    StringRequest request;
    public int notifNumber;
    public int notifNumberOriginal;
    Context context1;

    Context c2;

    SharedPreferences shp;

    int number = 0;
    int preNumber = 0;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context1 = this;

        shp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor shpE = shp.edit();

        if (!shp.contains("countNumber")) {
            shpE.putInt("countNumber", 10);
            shpE.apply();
        } else {

        }
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    newCount(context1);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 7000);
            }

        }, 7000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void newCount(final Context context) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        String url_notf_number = ..

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_notf_number, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        String r = response.substring(0, 14);
                        String number = r.replaceAll("\\D+", "");

                        notifNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        notifNumberOriginal = notifNumber;
                        c2 = context;
                        context1 = context;
                        subCount1();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void subCount1() {
        try {
            int number1 = (shp.getInt("lastNumber", 0));

            notifNumber = notifNumber - number1;

            if ((notifNumber != preNumber) && notifNumber > 0) {
                preNumber = notifNumber;

                boolean b = false;

                MediaPlayer ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(context1, R.raw.iphone);
                ourSong.start();
                try {
                    MainActivity.setMyy("reload");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I don't know if I do this correctly,I'd appreciate any help

Comment: I haven't worked with the `MediaPlayer` in some time now, but as far as I remember you need to release it after you're done with it. To me it looks like you're just creating new instances or references to the `MediaPlayer`. The `MediaPlayer` is a singleton, but if you're spurting out new references to it all the time, I wonder if this could cause a lot of memory usage? See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release() for some info about `release()` and when to use it etc.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for `create()` as well: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaPlayer#create - it states that it can throw an exception if too many MediaPlayers are created.

Comment: @Darwind tnx for your answer but if you notice, the error I get returns to new Request queue. I really don't know what to use when I want to make a Json request continuously in service

Comment: It could just be a symptom basically. You're creating Volley requests asynchronously in another thread, so it might be that it just gets to that specific execution when it runs out of memory. Have you checked that it's the exact same stacktrace you get every time?
Also have you tried to use `release()`? No matter what you should change that part.

Comment: @Darwind I'm testing my app,if I don't face the error I'll tell you. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Darwind  unfortunately after 10 hours that awful error appears..

Comment: @Darwind  can you tell me where I can release media player? yesterday I removed playing sound part and the error shown after 10 hours

Comment: Did you check whether it's the same stacktrace you get every time or is it somewhere else now? If it's still inside the Volley code, I'd suggest you try and remove that part of the code and see if it still crashes after a certain amount of time.